# the view port is very laggy

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

hey all I am just trying to add bones to my character mesh and I have hair on my character but the problem is I am trying to add bones to rig it and animate it but I cant cause of the lag how can I disable the hair so I can animate it thanks in advance , will upload my blend file
[image]

Edit : I just fixed it by going the modifier and disable realtime display on every modifier

Comment: It looks like it's your hair objects that make your scene very heavy, if I delete them the viewport is not laggy anymore

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: thank you for the tip moon just wanted to keep the hair or maybe hide it until i animate the object , Thank you duarte for the info i will make sure next time to upload more details without blend file until u guys ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This icon will hide the particle system in the viewport, the camera will disable it for renders.

You could also disable the particle system modifier in a similar manner, which may make sense if you had other modifiers you wanted to disable and needed to keep everything organized.